# Why isn't my Platypus-built app accepting dropped folders?

Tags: mac, applications, python

I have a little Python 2.7 script I turned into an app using Platypus a number of years ago.  After updating Platypus to the latest version (5.4.1) I just wanted to rebuild the app so it would start honoring the system's Light/Dark/Auto Appearance setting (which the latest Platypus supports).  But the app that is built will no longer accept folders dropped on its window (whereas it always used to).

I have "Accept dropped items" checked.

In Settings I have both the "public.item" and "public.folder" UTIs.

Reading Platypus documentation and looking around in the app, that seems to be all that is required.  But the open window totally ignores folders dropped on it.  I have confirmed that *no* code is executed.  However, dropping a file on it works, because my own Python code first checks to make sure it got a folder and complains if that is not the case.  A datetime.datetime.now() stamp at the head of main() prints when a file is dropped on the app, but not when a folder is dropped on the app.

I'm probably missing something trivial and stupid, but it is as if Platypus-built applications simply no longer process folders dropped on their windows.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the latest Platypus has a bug of some kind that affects new apps built from an existing .platypus file that was saved by an older version of Platypus.  I was able to build a full-functioning version of my app by simply starting from a clean slate and entering the necessary information and adjusting the relevant settings.  So the solution is just to start over.  Fortunately, setting things up from scratch is pretty easy.